# how can ı distrubute $1000

Tags: combinatorics

A author writes a book and then he publishs it.He realises that there are some mistakes but he do not know how many mistakes are there and he decides to distribute \$1000 someone who find the mistakes.After then two people say that we find some mistakes, the first one finds 60 mistakes and the second one finds 70 mistakes but 30 of them are the same.how many different ways this author can distribute \$1000.
I am confused because no one knows how many mistakes are there.
(this question was not in english, ı translated it and my english is not very well, sorry!)

Comment: Are you sure you translated the entire question? There's many different ways to interpret it as is.

Comment: There are totally $100 = 60+70-30$ mistakes found. If one want to assign 1000 bucks to these 100 mistakes, each mistake worth 10 buck. If a mistake is found by more than one person, just split the 10 buck equally among all who find that mistake. So the first person get $(60-30)+30/2 = 45$ while the second person get $(70-3)+30/2 = 55$.

Comment: yes ı am sure, ı asked it many many times

Answer (score 1):

This means that there are at least 100 mistakes. Let's call the number of unique mistakes each person found $A$ and $B$ respectively.  Let's also call the number of commonly found mistakes $C$.

\begin{equation}A = 70 - 30 = 40\end{equation}
\begin{equation}B = 60 - 30 = 30\end{equation}
\begin{equation}Total = A + B + C = 40 + 30 + 30 = 100\end{equation}

A fair way to distribute this would be as Achille Hui mentioned, Unique mistakes get 10, Common mistakes get 5.

But what they're asking for is how many DIFFERENT ways are there to distribute the $1,000.

Let's call the amount per unique mistakes Person 1 found to be $a$, the unique mistakes Person 2 found $b$, and the common mistakes $c$.

\begin{equation}\$1000 = 40a + 30b + 30c\end{equation}

You want all the combinations of $a$, $b$, and $c$ that satisfy this equation because those are all the ways you can distribute \$1000, fairly or not.

This is as far as I can go with this answer at the moment, but hopefully this gives you somewhere to start. You can probably assume $a$, $b$, and $c$ are natural numbers or rational numbers no smaller than $0.01$ (a penny).

Comment: ı try to solve it but ı guess we should say there are n mistakes totally,100 are known but (n-100) are unknown, and we will continue with this assumption